# std::string not accessible after converting from QString

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QDialog which has a QLineEdit and a slot connected to the QLineEdit's textChanged signal.

```cpp
std::string gname;

void NewMsgDialog::nameChanged(QString str) {
    auto temp = str.toUtf8().constData();
    gname = str.toStdString();
}
```

In the debugger I can see that temp has a sensible content (e. g. "my text") but at the end of the function, gname's value says "<not accessible>". And really, if I use gname from another function, I get a SEGFAULT.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has **undefined behavior**.

`str.toUtf8()` returns a *temporary* `QByteArray`, which you are calling `constData()` on to get a pointer to its `char` data, which you are saving to `temp`. But then the `QByteArray` goes out of scope after that assignment, leaving `temp` pointing to freed memory before it can be used in the `std::string{temp}` construction.

You don't need the `temp` variable. `std::string` has an `operator=` that takes a `const char*` as input. By assigning the return value of `constData()` directly to `gname`, the `QByteArray` stays in scope until after the assignment:

```cpp
std::string gname; 

void NewMsgDialog::nameChanged(QString str) {
    gname = str.toUtf8().constData();
}
```

Even simpler, you can use `str.toStdString()` instead, which returns a UTF-8 encoded `std::string`:

```cpp
std::string gname; 

NewMsgDialog::nameChanged(QString str) {
    gname = str.toStdString();
}
```

Comment: So just removing the `temp` variable and assigning directly to `gname` is the solution?

Comment: Also, I think that you can't change gname because of `const` in front of `std::string gname;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I updated the code with the suggestions you gave, but I still get the problem. (I updated the question with the new code.)

Comment: @sfphoton But you haven't, you still have the `temp` variable. That is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `gname = str.toStdString();`

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out, it was a bug of QT Creator's debugger. When not run in debug, gname was assigned a value just fine. Anyway, I got really useful tips from the other answers.

Comment: your initial code with the `temp` variable is wrong, it can only work by accident, possibly as a result of compiler optimizations